# Cross Table no MySql

Tags: mysql, join

Alguém sabe como implementar uma Cross Table no MySql para poder me ajudar? Preciso transformar uma query que retorna sempre 4 linhas de resultado para apenas 1 linha colocando cada campo das linha em colunas uma ao lado da outra, como ilustrado na imagem abaixo. OBS: os valores do campo fila podem sempre variar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: `fila_1`, `fila_2`.... só serão 4 filas ou é variável também ?

Comment: Somente 4 filas, porém pode haver casos onde possua apenas 3 filas. A ideia é para fazer um cálculo de quanto tempo cada ticket ficou em cada fila, eu já criei uma function para fazer esse cálculo, porém os parâmetros a ser passado para a function é o número do ticket e o número da fila, dai o retorno da function será o tempo entre uma fila e outra, por exemplo: 02:00:00 por isso preciso que o resultado seja tudo em apenas uma linha, igual na tabela 2.

Comment: A ordem dos registros vc quis dizer? Existe o campo id que ficou omitido na tabela 1, só considerar que cada linha tem um id único, tentei com subselect mas sem sucesso.

Comment: @Rovann Linhalis os números 37, 12, 20 e 35 são os Id's das Filas as quais esse ticket de número 61100 passou, essa tabela é um histórico num sistema de tickets.

Comment: Um novo ticket sempre terá o primeiro registro na fila 37 e sempre com o history_id = 1. Dai quando mudar de fila o history_id sempre será = 16 e o id da Fila pode variar, cada fila possui seu id único.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**V**ocê pode usar vários sub-selects para isso, pelo que percebi, a ordem das colunas é dada pela coluna data, e sempre serão 4 colunas. Sendo assim:

```
select distinct
h.ticket,
(select x.fila from historico x where x.ticket = h.ticket order by data limit 1) as fila_1,
(select x.data from historico x where x.ticket = h.ticket order by data limit 1) as data_fila_1,

(select x.fila from historico x where x.ticket = h.ticket order by data limit 1 offset 1) as fila_2,
(select x.data from historico x where x.ticket = h.ticket order by data limit 1 offset 1) as data_fila_2,

(select x.fila from historico x where x.ticket = h.ticket order by data limit 1 offset 2) as fila_3,
(select x.data from historico x where x.ticket = h.ticket order by data limit 1 offset 2) as data_fila_3,

(select x.fila from historico x where x.ticket = h.ticket order by data limit 1 offset 3) as fila_4,
(select x.data from historico x where x.ticket = h.ticket order by data limit 1 offset 3) as data_fila_4
from historico h
```

> Resultado:

```
ticket  fila_1  data_fila_1 fila_2  data_fila_2 fila_3  data_fila_3 fila_4  data_fila_4
61100   37  2018-06-01T10:00:00Z    12  2018-06-01T18:00:00Z    20  2018-06-04T09:00:00Z    35  2018-06-05T17:00:00Z
71100   37  2018-06-02T10:00:00Z    12  2018-06-02T18:00:00Z    20  2018-06-05T09:00:00Z    35  2018-06-06T17:00:00Z
```

Coloquei no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/96b421/2)

Obs: Inseri um outro ticket de exemplo.

Comment: era isso mesmo, perfeito! Só uma dúvida, vc criou a tabela com o formato da date como TIMESTAMP, na minha tabela aqui no banco está como DATETIME e quando rodo a query não funciona como no seu exemplo, está repetindo o primeiro registro em todas as colunas, será que é devido ao formato do campo data?

Comment: acho que não... se puder mandar o script que cria a tabela... posso ver... vi nas suas perguntas que várias delas estão em aberto ainda, não se esqueça de marcar como respondida. Caso tenha dúvidas acesse o [Tour]

Comment: tinha faltado o distinct... alterei pra datetime tambem a coluna e não mudou nada....

Comment: A estrutura da tabela é essa:

CREATE TABLE ticket_history (  id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, history_type_id smallint(6) NOT NULL,  ticket_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,  queue_id int(11) NOT NULL,  create_time datetime NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;